# How to use skipTests option when using mvn-ant-tasks in ant

Tags: maven, ant

I am using `mvn-ant-task` in a build file to clean and install the Maven projects.

Below is the configuration I did

```
<project name="maven-project"
     default="default"
     xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">
```

and in the target, I have added something like this

```
<target name="CleanInstall">
    <echo message="Building the project using maven and skipping tests if any in ${RepoFolder}" />
    <artifact:mvn pom="${GIT_REPO_HOME}\${RepoFolder}\pom.xml">
        <arg value="clean:clean" />
    </artifact:mvn>
    <artifact:mvn pom="${GIT_REPO_HOME}\${RepoFolder}\pom.xml">
        <arg value="install:install -DskipTests=true" />
    </artifact:mvn>
</target>
```

When I run this build, `clean` is processing properly, but I am unable to send the arguments `skipTests` in the install plugin.

Is there any other way to execute the Maven commands from Ant? I also tried

```
<exec command="mvn install -DskipTests=true" dir=""${GIT_REPO_HOME}\${RepoFolder}\pom.xml"/>
```

Its failing with error given below

> C:\Users\sharath\Desktop\devsetup\build.xml:102: Execute failed:
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory
>   "D:\sbhaskara\GIT\connectmodel"): CreateProcess error=2, The system
>   cannot find the file specified

Comment: Hey Tunaki, thanks a tot it worked like a charm. One other small request, is now am having issues with eclipse goal, as detailed below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not building the argument for the task correctly, it should be:

```xml
<target name="CleanInstall">
    <echo message="Building the project using maven and skipping tests if any in ${RepoFolder}" />
    <artifact:mvn pom="${GIT_REPO_HOME}\${RepoFolder}\pom.xml" >
        <arg value="-Dmaven.test.skip=true" />
        <arg value="clean" />
        <arg value="install" />
    </artifact:mvn>
</target>
```

i.e. each argument must be in its own `<arg>` tag. Note that I collapsed all the calls to Maven inside a single task.